# Android get image uploaded via web app on the database containing image filename and path

Tags: php, android, mysql, image, file-upload

I am thinking this through, please correct me if I am wrong, I know you can upload an image on the database either by using blob data or by storing the path of image file in the database. I am curious if I use the second mentioned, how can I get the image in an ANDROID mobile app when the path is from a folder here in the pc, is it even possible?

Comment: Well, you can set an IIS server (on windows for example) on your pc and then use it as your image server.

Comment: Can I use FileZilla on xampp for example?

Comment: 'I know you can upload an image on the database either by using blob data or by storing the path of image file in the database'. Wrong. If you are only storing a path you are not uploading an image at all. Moreover you did not tell where your database resides. If the database is on a different computer as your image then how would you get to the image once you have it's path?

Comment: Sorry my wording might lead to misinterpretation. I, for example uploaded an image file from my desktop, my upload path, let's say is in the "uploads" folder in my root directory. When I have successfully uploaded the file, it will have the path uploads/random.jpg so let's say I will store that in a database and not the image itself. So, what I was thinking is how do i get the image in that uploads file on my PC to the mobile device.